# Array.prototype causing error

Tags: javascript, arrays, w2ui

Am trying to implement `w2ui` [multi select](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!fields/fields-4) in one of d3 charts which am working on.

This is the link to sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z4dhpyh/) with the problem.

I have three function :

```
//get a column of an array
Array.prototype.getColumn = function(name) {
  return this.map(function(el) {
    // gets corresponding 'column'
    if (el.hasOwnProperty(name)) return el[name];
    // removes undefined values
  }).filter(function(el) {
    return typeof el != 'undefined';
  });
};
//remove duplicates in an array
Array.prototype.contains = function(v) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] === v) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (!arr.contains(this[i])) {
      arr.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I need to implement these three in one of my functions.

Problem is that, whenever I try to implement these functions with `Array.prototype` I get items in the multiselect as `"undefined"`. The number of   `"undefined"` is directly propotional to the number of functons with `Array.prototype` functions.

If I remove these functions, I can get the multi-select to work properly(only the multi-select part, not the chart as a whole. I don't understand, what's causing the error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you've just learned why it's a bad idea to modify native prototypes. Now make those regular functions instead.

Comment: And you've just learned why it's a bad idea to do anything without having a whole plan for your execution environment. You can modify native prototypes with no problem as long as you require coding standards that don't conflict with that decision.

Comment: So If I implement the functionalities as separate function, it'll work?

Comment: Libraries that don't respect the fact that JS is a shared environment may, for example, use `for-in` to iterate an Array. Because this includes all enumerable properties *(including inherited ones)*, it can bump into your extensions. Personally, I'd file a [bug report](https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues), but that's up to you. Or just take adeneo's advice.

Comment: ...and by the way, this problem isn't unique to custom extensions. You'd have the same problem with polyfills, and they should take that into account if their library supports IE8.

Comment: w2ui contributor here. This should be fixed in w2ui 1.5, see my pull request from March: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/pull/1194/files - you're linking an old 1.5 JS in your jsfiddle, if you use the one from the `dist` folder it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4z4dhpyh/1/

Comment: @mpf82, the jsfiddle which you posted, is not working. The drop down is not coming in that. And should I take both `w2ui.css` and `w2ui.js` from the dist folder?

Comment: @squint, thanks a lot for the info. i'll try to come up with my own implementation as told by adeneo in sometime. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome was complaining about the mime type, worked fine in FF. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4z4dhpyh/2/ - and yes, you should use the latest js and css from the dist folder. But note that 1.5 is not (yet) released as stable. The latest stable is 1.4.3 which you can get from the w2ui homepage.

Comment: @driftking9987: You're welcome. Since this library seems to not support IE8, you should be safe using the answer provided below. This makes the methods you add non-enumerable, so there won't be any collision. Good to see they're fixing it though. Looking at the source, they seemed pretty responsible about iterating arrays.

Comment: ...also, just FYI, ES7 has an `.includes()` method that is basically the same as your `.contains()`. A [patch is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill), but again, use `Object.defineProperty` as below.

Comment: Considering all the fact, I decided to implement my own functions rather than using `Array.prototype`. As mentioned by @mpf82, the w2ui is not stable one so I guess there is not point taking risk. And the given answer is correct but then it's a workaround, I guess i'll be better away with my own implementation.

Comment: Taking your functions off the `.prototype` is definitely a valid solution, though I wouldn't call the answer below a workaround. It's actually the way it should be done in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general messing with the core javascript objects is a bad idea when you are working with the third party libraries. If you still want to keep it this way and solve this particular problem use the Object.defineProperty method, turning off the enumerable bit

So for example change

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(v) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] === v) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

to

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(v) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === v) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

and similar for other prototype method that you have added.

Comment: Thanks @Hector, it does solves the issue, but I implemented another function to get the things done rather than using `Array.prototype`. Since it's working solution, i'll accept the answer. Might help someone.

Comment: addition: you may want to add the property `writable: true,` (e.g. below `enumerable: false`) to ensure compatibility with other libraries that redefine prototype methods, otherwise they'll cause an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'contains' of object...`. See https://github.com/opensheetmusicdisplay/opensheetmusicdisplay/issues/980